# JavaScript function does not fire

Tags: javascript, mobile, web

I am working on building a mobile page that uses JavaScript to make the top menu drop down and close as well, but it is not working.
Here's the JS

```
<script>
window.onload = function () { 
var elem = document.getElementById('navBarMobile');
var burger = document.getElementById('hamburgerMobile');
var cross = document.getElementById('crossMobile');
}

function menuExpand() {

    elem.style.transition = "height 1s linear 0s";
    elem.style.height = "292px";

    burger.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    burger.style.opacity = "0";
    burger.style.zIndex = "0";

    cross.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0.5s"
    cross.style.opacity = "1";
    cross.style.zIndex = "1";
}

function menuClose() {

    elem.style.transition = "height 1s linear 0s";
    elem.style.height = "87px";

    burger.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0.5s";
    burger.style.opacity = "1";
    burger.style.zIndex = "1";

    cross.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    cross.style.opacity = "0";
    burger.style.zIndex = "0";
}
</script>
```

And the html

```
<div id="hamburgerMobile" onclick="menuExpand();"></div>
<div id="crossMobile" onclick="menuClose();"></div>
```

Before, I had the declaration statements seen at the top in their designated spots inside of the function, but each function was firing only once.

Comment: Declare variable directly instead of window.load function

Answer (score 5):

Variables `elem`, `burger` and `cross` are defined in different scope and it is not visible form your functions.

You should try to declare it earlier:

```
var elem;
var burger;
var cross;

window.onload = function () { 
  elem = document.getElementById('navBarMobile');
  burger = document.getElementById('hamburgerMobile');
  cross = document.getElementById('crossMobile');
}
```

Read about function scopes:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I threw that in, but each function is still only firing once and I don't know why...

Comment: Oh actually, I just realized in the last line of code in JS I accidentally typed burger instead of cross, so this was putting the cross on top when it was already closed.